# Determine 64-bit file size in C on MinGW 32-bit

Tags: c, mingw, filesize

I'm going crazy trying to get this to work in MinGW 32-bit.  It works on all other platforms I've tried.

All I want to do is get the size of a > 4GB file into a 64-bit int.

This works fine on other platforms:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS   64
#include <sys/stat.h>

int64_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```

I tried adding the following defines before the above code, based on various suggestions I found online:

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE   1
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 1
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64   1
```

Also tried:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
#define off_t off64_t
#endif
```

And finally tried adding -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to the gcc flags (should be the same as the above define though...)

No luck.  The returned int64_t is still getting truncated to a 32-bit value.

What is the right way to determine a 64-bit file size in MinGW 32-bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks guys, good suggestions but I figured it out... MinGW requires this define to enable the struct __stat64 and the function _stat64:

```
#if __MINGW32__
#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x0601
#endif
```

Then this works:

```
int64_t fsize(const char *filename) {

#if __MINGW32__
    struct __stat64 st; 
    if (_stat64(filename, &st) == 0)
#else
    struct stat st; 
    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
#endif

        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have MinGW handy right now, but if I recall correctly there is a `_stat64` function what uses a `struct __stat64`. You will probably want to hide this ugliness with some cunning macros!

Comment: There's probably no need to get too cunning - just an `#if _WIN32/#else/#endif` in the `fsize()` function.

Comment: @MichaelBurr As long as `fsize()` is the only place he/she uses `stat`. (When I typed cunning my tongue was firmly in my cheek!)

Comment: This works but _stat64 is only available in MinGW if you add this before #include <sys/stat.h>, otherwise the stat64 symbols won't resolve: #define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x0601

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lseek64` if that exists in the MinGW package

```
   #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE     /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   off64_t lseek64(int fd, off64_t offset, int whence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Windows API [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) to get the file size for an open handle, or [`GetFileAttributesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) A/W for a filename.

For a working example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991228/1505939 .